# Как сделать событие в потоке?

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, delphi-7, com

Проблема в том что если я буду перемещать или изменять форму событие не будет срабатывать.

У меня есть событие procedure TForm1.ComPortRxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer); компонента TComPort в котором есть ComPort.ReadStr(Str, Count); и если я начинаю мучать форму то это событие не обрабатываеться.

Возможно ли ComPortRxChar завернуть в поток ? И как это сделать ? Или есть другие варианты решения ?

Comment: Что нужно делать с принятыми данными?

Comment: @MBO - данные нужно вывести на экран

Comment: Советую присмотреться к версиям по новее, там нет проблем с RTTI, и было не мало багов исправлено с синхронизацией потоков. Вы можете использовать **TEvent** в качестве отправки и приема данных по событию.